# Latest active Date result in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table TABLE_X with following data:

```
**Sales_ID   Start_Date  End_Date**
 S0001   01-01-2010  31-12-2020
 S0002   01-01-2011  31-12-2021
 S0003   01-01-2012  31-12-2012
 S0004   01-01-2010  31-12-2019
```

Now i need to write a a SQL Query to have a most latest start and end date and the result would be

```
**Sales_ID    Start_Date      End_Date**    
 S0002    01-01-2011      31-12-2021
```

Note that I am using Oracle DBMS. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from 
(
    select your_table.*, row_number() over (order by end_date desc, start_date desc) as seqnum
    from your_table
) t
where seqnum = 1
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0b334/1)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12, you can also do:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by end_date desc, start_date desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```